# redux-form Validation: min length and matching password

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to validate matching password and confirm password and minimum input length. Here is my code:

```
<Field
              name='password'
              label='Password'
              component={renderField}
              as={Form.Input}
              type='password'
              icon='lock'iconPosition='left'
              placeholder='Password'
              validate={[minLength(5), required ]}/>
              <Field
                  name='password1'
                  label='Confirm Password'
                  icon="lock" iconPosition='left'
                  component={renderField}
                  as={Form.Input}
                  type='password'

                  placeholder='Confirm'
                  validate={[passwordValidate, required ]}/>
```

I do not know why it is not working. Here is my validation code:

```
export const passwordValidate  = (value, allValues) =>
{
    value !== allValues.password ? 'Password does not match' : undefined;
}

export const minLength = len => value =>
{
    value && value.length < len ? `Must have greater than ${len}` : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this even I faced the same issue. Hope it works for you as well.

```
const minLengthName = minLength(5);
```

Now call validate like this:

```
validate={[minLengthName, required ]}
```

Comment: post your form tag code, want to check how your are using onSubmit.